# Unlocking information on weapon upgrades

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I have noticed that the information on a weapon upgrade is not always available. Sometimes only the materials required is known but the stats is not, sometimes both. This makes it harder to decide if it is worth the effort gathering the materials for an upgrade.

What is the criteria for seeing the upgraded stats in-game and is there anyway to unlock it faster(without gathering the materials required)?

I know these information is/will be available online, but it is kind of weird to be constantly going between my phone/computer and PS4 while playing. It will be nicer if I can just see what is the stats of my next weapon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will see the stats of an unlockable weapon as soon as you have gathered **all items required to craft it**.

Without any external resources the only way of finding out what those items are, is guessing. There are some indicators of where the items are from (Color, Icon etc) but It's no guarantee since sometimes monsters drop materials with icons similar to let's say an ore.

Don't worry though. If you're playing the game and hunt as many different monsters as possible you'll see all of the stats soon enough!

Comment: `topmost item` that's the key! At least I can see the stats of the weapon and decide if I want to go for it

Comment: topmost item is usually the rarest one of the recipe. So if you get that, you'll probably already have everything else to craft it :P

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  As you can see [in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2AMW.jpg), I have the topmost material, but no information is available.  I believe you are required to know what all the materials are, not just the top one.

Comment: There are some additional things I noticed that have an influence on weapon stats being displayed. I'll update those as soon as I find a confirmation to them.

Comment: Some more anecdotal evidence: I had a Gunlance that was all question marks, until after the Zorah fight.  Then, even though I hadn't gotten any of the materials for it yet, it showed up.  Perhaps there are multiple ways to unlock them?